# Can I get Intellitrace from a Application Insights exception in Azure ?

Tags: debugging, azure, intellitrace

I see the exceptions and details of it but what I want to know is the state of the variables when that happen. So I think what I need is the intellitrace file to load into VS2015 right?  Or am I missing something?  I looked around and cannot find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliTrace does not capture values of local variables. As far as I know because of performance reasons. It only records values of actual parameters and values returned from methods. However, there is also a limitations here. If an actual parameter (or a return value) is of a reference type, IntelliTrace will not capture the whole object graph but only the first level. For example, let's assume that there is class A. It has 2 properties:

```
int IntProp { get; set; }
SomeClass ObjectProp { get; set; }
```

In this case IntelliTrace will allow us to only examine  a value of `IntProp`. As to `ObjectProp`, we'll able to only see if it is set or not. It won't be possible to see properties of  an instance of `SomeClass`.

Comment: So in the case where I am getting an exception when clients are running my code but I need to know more like the state of all the variables is the best thing to do is just start adding a bunch of variables as custom parameters ?  Is there some easy way to get every object at the point of exception and dump it in application insights ?

Comment: There are some workarounds but they requite additional effort. You can try to: define custom diagnostic events, use 
IProgrammableDataQuery interaface, create tracepoints and use IntelliTrace together with live debugging. However, only the first two can be used in the production. Besides, they will not allow you to capture all the variables but only selected.